# RFC_ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE: Name or password is incorrect

Tags: android, sup

I have created an application with SAP as backend.

My application is having following error:

> com.sap.mw.jco.JCO$Exception: (103) RFC_ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE: Name or password is incorrect (repeat logon) while trying for synchronizing with the mbos.

I read in earlier posts that this error is because of "incorrect username and password". Can someone kindly guide me as to what could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, this happens when the RFC is getting executed and its authentication parameters are incorrect.

This can be corrected in the SUP work space.Authentication details need to be changed in SUP connection Profile under Enterprise Explorer Window.

You can then check this by Pinging the server/ Taking Preview of your MBO.

Caution: Multiple trials to Ping the EIS/ preview MBO with incorrect Password can Lock your System.